# In primefaces dataTable Sort and Filter Not Preserved with Poll

Tags: jsf, sorting, web, primefaces, polling

I have been trying to get the sorting and filtering preserved while poll updates the table. Unfortunately, I was not able to do that.

When dataTable is refreshed every two seconds, or any interval, by poll, the filter value is removed and column, when clicked on, only sorts ascending no matter how many times column header is clicked. Also, the sorting arrow always shows as "descending".

Unless I have missed something, I think this is a bug in dataTable.

Please take a look at this and let me know if a this is bug, or my implementation is incorrect. I have been trying to get this to work for couple days now. Any help would be greatly appreciate it.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
               xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
               xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
               xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
               xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">

            <f:view contentType="text/html">

               <h:head>
               </h:head>

               <h:body>

                  <h:form id="pollForm">
                     <p:poll id="poll" widgetVar="pollVar" interval="2"
                        listener="#{tableBean.update}" async="true" autoStart="true" />
                  </h:form>

                  <h:form>

                     <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
                        <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}">
                           <f:facet name="header">  
                              Ajax Sorting  
                          </f:facet>

                           <p:column sortBy="#{car.model}">
                              <f:facet name="header">
                                 <h:outputText value="Model" />
                              </f:facet>
                              <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
                           </p:column>

                           <p:column sortBy="#{car.year}">
                              <f:facet name="header">
                                 <h:outputText value="Year" />
                              </f:facet>
                              <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
                           </p:column>

                           <p:column sortBy="#{car.manufacturer}" 
                              filterBy="#{car.manufacturer}">
                              <f:facet name="header">
                                 <h:outputText value="Manufacturer" />
                              </f:facet>
                              <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />
                           </p:column>

                           <p:column sortBy="#{car.color}">
                              <f:facet name="header">
                                 <h:outputText value="Color" />
                              </f:facet>
                              <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
                           </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
                     </p:outputPanel>
                  </h:form>

               </h:body>

            </f:view>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to give an Id to your dataTable and then call dataTableId.filter? It works for me.

```
<p:poll id="pollAutoUpdate" interval="5" oncomplete="entityTable.filter()" autoStart="false" stop="true" widgetVar="myPoll" />
```